# Software for burning multiple dvds when 1 dvd is not big enough

Tags: macos, dvd-burning

Consider the scenario where one has 10Gb of pictures they want to backup to DVD.  Obviously, this will not fit on one DVD.  However, 3 DVDs would do the trick just fine.

Is there software that will help automate the process of queuing or splitting up the files and then burning to multiple DVDs?

I know I can go in and copy/paste into 3 directories, and then manually split the files into them, but wasn't sure if there was something out there to help automate this process - particularly since it is something I want to do fairly regularly as part of my backup process.

Comment: I doubt this will be a problem very long because of all the hype surrounding Blu-Ray, Amazon's S3, External HDs, etc. this won't be a problem very long.

Comment: @digitxp That's great, in this mythical future.  But I'm in the here and now.  And one of the reasons for DVD's is I can pass the pictures to family easily (which makes the backup an offsite backup, which is awesome)

Answer (score 1):

Most 3rd party burning softwares support disc spanning when queuing up large amounts of files for burning to disc.

Nero
Roxio to mention a couple.

Comment: Yeah, what Moab said.  That's the basic idea of pretty much ALL backup software as far as I know -- regardless of the target media.